# intrinsis function not found on vs 2015

Tags: x86, intel, sse, intrinsics

I work with visual studio 2015, I need function _mm_div_epi8(CPUID Flags: SSE) but I cannot using _mm_div_epi8 in my code, Vs 2015 declare it's undefined, did I do something wrong? 
I search and found function had exist:
https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3813,18,1855,6026,3262,152,621,893,885,893,4913,294,294,893,611,893,3804,893,4988,4913,4913,2132,3101,3099,1645,2123,2153,2098,2100,2107&text=_mm_div_epi8

Comment: `_mm_div_epi8` is not an SSE intrinsic. It is part of Intel's SVML library, which is part of the Intel icc compiler. Maybe you can use [Agner Fog's VCL](https://www.agner.org/optimize/vectorclass.pdf) as an alternative.

Comment: @wim: can you retag this sse and/or x86 so I can dup-hammer it to [SSE integer division?](//stackoverflow.com/q/16822757)  (And maybe a Q&A about SVML functions not being intrinsics, just confusingly named the same way.)  Also worth mentioning http://libdivide.com/